# SPLIT_PART with 2 delimiters with OR condition Snowflake

Tags: sql, split, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I am trying to use SPLIT_PART to retrieve value available after the symbols '.' **or** ':'.

Example -

```
data = 'first.middle.last'
split_part(data,'.',-1) 


data = 'first.middle:last' 
split_part(data,':',-1)
```

In both of the cases, result will be 'last'

How can I use something like `split_part(data," : OR .", -1)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the REGEX function or just change all characters to one:

```
SET data = 'first.middle:last';
SELECT SPLIT_PART(REPLACE($data, '.', ':'),':',-1);
```

Comment: That was easy, thank you @Michael Golos

Answer (score 1):

You could replace `:` with `.` before parsing

```
split_part(replace(data,'.',':'),':',-1)
```

You could also nest it inside another `split_part` if the first one doesn't fetch anything

```
split_part(split_part(data,'.',-1),':',-1)
```

Comment: The first option worked better for my situation. Thank you!